# Newton vs Leibniz notation

Tags: calculus, notation

I have often come across the cursory remarks made here and there in calculus lectures , math documentaries or in calculus textbooks that Leibniz's notation for calculus is better off than that of Newton's and is thus more widely used.

Though I have always followed Leibniz's notation( matter of familiarity, as that's what I have been taught) , but of late I had the idea of following Newton's notation just to see where I could get stuck just because of "notational" issues.

Is there any limitation of Newton's notation that I might encounter while doing calculus ; and which may make it seem a bad idea to do calculus in Newton's notation?

Here "Leibniz notation" is $\frac{dy}{dx}$  for the derivative of $y$, and "Newton's notation" is $\dot{y}$ for the derivative of $y$.

Comment: Please show us what notations you are referring to.

Comment: @YvesDaoust "Leibnitz notation" is $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for the derivative of $y$, whereas "Newton's notation" is $y'$ or $\dot{y}$

Comment: When I took a Control Theory course I used almost exclusively Newton's notation, possibly for practicality. On the other hand, for Dynamic Systems  it's really practical to use both. Finally, when you work some Chemistry or Physics, Leibniz's notation might be more natural because it shows differentiation wrt to something specific.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: there are also Leibniz' and Newton's notations for the antiderivatives. I'd prefer the OP to comment.

Comment: I concur with Omnomnomnom and my question is related to the notations that has been mentioned in his comment.

Comment: @naveendankal nevertheless, I agree with Yves that this is the sort of context to the question that should ideally have been included in your original post.

Comment: On second thought I too feel the same , I just assumed that by just mentioning the Newton's and Leibniz's notation would suffice .

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Actually, only ẏ is Newton's notation. y′ is Lagrange's notation.

Comment: Google on "Johnathan Bartlett". Leibniz Notation is far more algebraic, and you CAN treat differentials as ratios when you do it correctly using implicit diff only with operator d. $d[d[f]] = d^2[f]$. $d[d[y]/d[x]]]/d[x] = (ddy)/(dx)^2 - (dy/dx)(ddx/(dx)^2)$ ... careful that standard Leibniz notation implicitly assumes $d^2[x] = 0$, which is true when $x$ is a line.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Regarding the notations for the derivative:

**Upsides of using Leibniz notation:**

- It makes most consequences of the chain rule "intuitive".  In particular, it is easier to see that $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx}$ than it is to see that $[f(g(x))]' = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$.  See also $u$-substitution, in which we "define $du := \frac{du}{dx}dx$".
- In a physical/scientific setting, it makes it obvious what the units of the new expression (integral or derivative) should be.  For instance, if $s$ is in meters and $t$ is in seconds, clearly $\frac{ds}{dt}$ should be in meters/second.

**Downsides:**

- It is harder/clumsier to keep track of arguments of the derivative with this notation.  For instance, I can more easily write and keep track of $f'(2)$ than I can $\left.\frac{dy}{dx} \right|_{x=2}$
- It often leads to the mistaken notion that [$\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a ratio](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/21199/81360)

Notably, almost no one uses Newton's notation for the integral ("antiderivative"), in which the antiderivative of $x(t)$ is $\bar x(t)$, $\overset{|}{x}(t)$, or $X(t)$ (though this last one occasionally is used in introductory textbooks).  Leibniz notation seems to be the clear winner in that regard.

Comment: Newton's earliest use of dots, to indicate velocities or fluxions [i.e. derivative with respect to time] is found on a leaf dated May 20, 1665. Newton never used $f'$. Lagrange in his *Theorie des fonctions analytiques* (1797) introduced the new symbols : $f'x$ for the *first derivative*, $f''x$ for the first derivative of $f'x$, and so on ... See [Cajori](https://books.google.it/books?id=bT5suOONXlgC&pg=PA207) § 575.

Comment: In his [Tractatus de quadratura curvarum](https://books.google.it/books?id=T4JYAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA7) (1704) Newton uses a vertical bar (and not horizontal) on $x$ to indicate the quantity whose fluxion is $x$.

Comment: In [Principia](https://books.google.it/books?id=XJwx0lnKvOgC&pg=PA251) (1687), Book II, Lemma II, Newton uses capital letters $A, B, C$ for fluents and small letters $a, b, c$ for their fluxions. In summary, Newton's signs of integration were never popular, not even in England : even the Newtonian [John Keill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Keill) mixed dots for fluxions and the Leibnizian $\int$ for integrals.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks for that. I'm content to leave your comments and my question as they are, but if you feel that something should be added directly to my answer, please do so.

Comment: No, thanks. The OP's question was not about "history" but about "benefits" of competing notations; thus, history decided (for Leibniz) and the reason you give are correct. The only aim of my comments is to add some historical facts about Newton's original notation.

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA : History does help in throwing some more light and make things look more meaningful. I deliberately did not mention Langrange's notation as I thought it was neither contemporary nor rivalry in nature with Newton and Leibniz's.

Comment: "It often leads to the mistaken notion that $dy/dx$ is a ratio." Actually sometimes you do treat it as a ratio: for example when solving linear differential equations by seperating the variables you multiply by $dy$ to get it to the other side.

Comment: @JannikPitt treating it as a ratio under justified circumstances is one thing. However, as is well-explained in the link, blindly treating $dy/dx$ as a ratio can lead to incorrect conclusions.

Comment: Wait, I use F(x) for antiderivatives of f(x). What's the Leibniz notation for that?

Comment: @MissMonicaE Leibniz used $d/dx$ as differentiation and $\int dx$ as "anti"-differentiation

Answer (score 11):

The most obvious difference is that the Leibnitz notation strictly defines what the independent variable is. In basic calculus we tend, as a rule, to derive a function "y" of a variable "x", but what happens when you want to derive the function
$w = 3x+4m$?
How would the Newton notation help you understand which is the variable and which is the parameter?

Also, in integrals, the notation makes methods like [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) or [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) much simpler as you use the "dx" symbol as if it were a substitutable variable.

Comment: In Newton's oroginal papers both variables $x$ and $y$ are "functions" of a common *parameter* $o$ (in the "intended" application, i.e. physics : $o$ is *time*). Thus, $\dot x$ is "equivalent to $dx/do$ and $\dot y$ to $dy/do$.

Answer (score 10):

I think it's best to use both notations simultaneously.

For instance, my preferred statement of the chain rule is:

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(y) = f'(y)\frac{d}{dx} y$$

For example, we can write:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \sin(x^3) = \sin'(x^3)\frac{d}{dx}x^3 = \cos(x^3)\cdot 3x^2 = 3x^2 \cos(x^3)$$

Try to do this using just Newtonian notation, or just Leibnizian notation; you'll quickly notice that both are harder.

There's also multivariable versions. For instance:

$$\frac{d}{dt}f(x,y) = (D_0 f)(x,y) \frac{d}{dt} x+(D_1 f)(x,y) \frac{d}{dt} y$$

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question.

Comment: i think i learned something from this answer thanks!

Comment: Here:
$$(f\circ g)' = (f'\circ g) \cdot g'$$

Answer (score 7):

Gottfried Liebniz developed his calculus around 1673 and published it at 1684, fifty years before Newton's work<sup>1</sup> on that subject was posthumously published. That could be one of the reasons why it is more widely used.

Additionally, that time difference in writing and publishing became a subject of rivalry over who of the two mathematicians first developed calculus, one of the direct implications of that conflict was the use of notation from the respective followers, leading to many difficulties for further developing of calculus in England<sup>2</sup> for many years.

Nowadays, both notations are being used interchangeably depending on the stage of the solution of the equation involving derivatives, for example: for algebraic manipulations one can use the more brief Newton notation, but when the time comes to *separate the variables* one writes the terms using Liebniz notation. Newton's notations (for derivatives) specifically is being more widely used in, *mechanics*, *electrical circuit analysis* and more generally in equations where differentiation is more obvious.

---

<sup>1. *Method of Fluxions* is the book in which Newton describes differential calculus and it was completed in 1671, but published in 1736.</sup>

<sup>2. An opinion described in *Men of Mathematics* by E. T. Bell</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia has a dedicated page on [notations for differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation), in short:

- Leibniz $\frac{dx}{dt}$
- Newton $\dot{x}$
- Lagrange $x'(t)$

Leibniz's notation is suggestive, thanks to the cancelling of the differentials
in the chain rule:
$$
\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}
$$
however great care must be taken, as this notation can also be **misleading for higher order derivatives**:
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\frac{dx^2}{dt^2}=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2
$$
which is **wrong**, the right formula is:
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}
$$
You have not this problem with Lagrange's notation:
$$
y(x(t))''=(y'(x(t))x'(t))'=y''(x(t))(x'(t))^2+y'(x(t))x''(t)
$$

These notation problems are well known when teaching differential calculus, see:

[H. Poincaré, La Notation Différentielle et l'enseignement (pdf)](http://henripoincarepapers.univ-lorraine.fr/chp/hp-pdf/hp1899em.pdf)

[J. Hadamard, La notion de différentielle dans l'enseignement (pdf)](https://dms.umontreal.ca/~delfour/Hadamard-1923.pdf)

unfortunately both in French, however you can find an English translation of Hadamard's article [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/296116506_Jacques_Salomon_Hadamard_and_the_Use_of_Symbols_in_Teaching_Differential_Calculus).

You can also see:

[Differentials, higher-order differentials and the derivative in the Leibnizian calculus (pdf)](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00327456.pdf)